# C#: Launch of PowerShell script won't execute from a Form application

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I'm writing a utility application which executes a powershell script, which further launches an .msi based installation after copying files from shared location. Calling this script Asynchronously using Powershell class. 
This is working fine in a console application, but hangs when called from a C# Form via Button click.
Here is the execution of Form:

```
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);
            Application.Run(new frm_MyApp_Update());
```

Here is the method used to call the Powershell script:

```
 private void ExecutePSFile(string scriptFile)
    {

        using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            // use "AddScript" to add the contents of a script file to the end of the execution pipeline.
            // use "AddCommand" to add individual commands/cmdlets to the end of the execution pipeline.
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(scriptFile));

            //Synchronus call
            //var psoutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

            // prepare a new collection to store output stream objects
            PSDataCollection<PSObject> outputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();

            //Invoking ASynchrounsly, so that we can do something else, while it is being executed in a separate thread.
            IAsyncResult result = PowerShellInstance.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outputCollection);

            //let's do something else, while script is bing executed.
            while (result.IsCompleted == false)
            {
                //Problem. Result.IsComplete is not getting true here  :(
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        }
    }
```

It invokes the script, but then trap in while (result.IsCompleted==false) loop i.e result.IsCompleted not getting true here.
Please note that this is working fine in a Console based application.

Here is the Powershell script used here:

```
$fileName="MyInstall.msi"
$sourcePath="\\MyServer\SharedDir\Installers\"
$targetPath=$Env:TEMP + "\My_tmp\"
$logFile=$targetPath + $fileName + ".log"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $targetPath -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host "Grabbing the latest installer..." -ForegroundColor Green
Copy-Item -Path @($sourcePath  + $fileName) -Destination $targetPath -Force  
Write-Host "Executing..." -ForegroundColor Green 
$MsiArguments = @("/i " + """$targetPath\$fileName""" + " /log " + $logFile)
Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $MsiArguments -Wait
Remove-Item $targetPath -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore| Out-Null
Write-Host "Finished Installation process..." -ForegroundColor Green
```

Is this a form threading issue? 
What I'm missing here in Form based application?

Any help would be really appreciated....

Comment: This is probably not the cause, but you have an unnecessary backslash here: `"""$targetPath\$fileName"""`

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.begininvoke

"When invoked using BeginInvoke, invocation doesn't
 finish until Input is closed. Caller of BeginInvoke must
 close the input buffer after all input has been written to
 input buffer. Input buffer is closed by calling
 Close() method.

If you want this command to execute as a standalone cmdlet
 (that is, using command-line parameters only),
 be sure to call Close() before calling BeginInvoke().  Otherwise,
 the command will be executed as though it had external input.
 If you observe that the command isn't doing anything,
 this may be the reason."

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused with Close() call.  From Input buffer, do you mean "PowerShellInstance.AddScript(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(scriptFile));"?

Same method works fine in Console based application, where I'm not calling any Close() method, neither did EndInvoke()...